# Using Julian Day and Count Data in the same GLM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, count-data, poisson-regression

I have count data in a poisson distribution.
My goal is to determine whether the 5 habitats surveyed (predictor variable) differ in their number of individuals (animals) (the response variable).
I am hoping to also evaluate whether Julian Day has an effect on the number of individuals in these habitats (i.e. over time). Is there a way to include this in the GLM?

Not all habitats are surveyed on each day.
E.g. DATASET:

| Habitat | # of Animals | Julian Day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lake | 5 | 167 |
| Pond | 4 | 167 |
| Lake | 2 | 169 |
| River | 4 | 170 |

Comment: What is the range of Julian day?  If it's small, as in the above example, it seems unlikely, unless say differing weather affected the ability to count (given that they are all water environments.)

Comment: ... correction ... seems unlikely to actually have an effect, I meant.